# How do I change text of my button using C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, button

I have a button.

```html
<button id="BtnName" class="roundBtns" type="button" > </button>
```

I need to display the length/count of values of different keys in my dictionary as my button text. 
My short snippet of my C# looks something like:

```
 if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("Apple"))
    {             
       BtnName.Text = AlertDic["Apple"].Split(',').Length;
    }

  if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("Samsung"))
     {
       BtnName.Text = AlertDic["Samsung"].Split(',').Length;
     }

 if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("Blackberry"))
    {
      BtnName.Text = AlertDic["Blackberry"].Split(',').Length;
    }
```

I tried to do this but I get the error that “HTML button does not contain definition for a TEXT and no accessible extension method for TEXT...”

I added runat= “server” and added .toString() as I kept getting “Cannot implicitly convert int to string” but no luck

Finally I also tried convert it into an asp button with runat=”server” but I get “Too many characters in character literal” error. 
It is not an on click event. It should show up when the page loads.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you sure you're using <asp:button> vs the html one (<button>)?

Comment: As Gus suggested, change your button to <asp: button

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't very clear in my question. It is simply a <button> tag. Not an input button like HTML's. I was using button group so all my buttons looked like <button></button>

Comment: @Shreeram as I mentioned in the question, when I change it to <asp:button> I get  “Too many characters in character literal” error.

Comment: `Too many characters in character literal` Somewhere in your code you are trying to stuff a string into a char type. So find out what line the error is talking about and double check that you are using `"` for a string and `'` for a single character. I would guess it's either where you use an index of the `AlertDic` or in one of your calls to `Split()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use a button using a `runat="server"` like this one:

```
<button id="BtnName" class="roundBtns" type="button" runat="server" > </button>
```

Change your code behind using the `InnerText` property and the `ToString` method like this one:

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("Apple"))
{             
   BtnName.InnerText = AlertDic["Apple"].Split(',').Length.ToString();
}

if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("Samsung"))
{
   BtnName.InnerText = AlertDic["Samsung"].Split(',').Length.ToString();
}

if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("Blackberry"))
{
   BtnName.InnerText = AlertDic["Blackberry"].Split(',').Length.ToString();
}
```